# C++ Replace string to char[]

Tags: c++, algorithm, multiplication

I have the following c++ program that multiple 2 large numbers :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>    
#define OVERFLOW 2
#define ROW b_len
#define COL a_len+b_len+OVERFLOW

using namespace std;

int getCarry(int num) {
    int carry = 0;
    if(num>=10) {
        while(num!=0) {
            carry = num %10;
            num = num/10;
        }
    }
    else carry = 0;
    return carry;
}

int num(char a) {
    return int(a)-48;
}

string mult(string a, string b) {
        string ret;
        int a_len = a.length();
        int b_len = b.length();
        int mat[ROW][COL];
        for(int i =0; i<ROW; ++i) {
            for(int j=0; j<COL; ++j) {
                mat[i][j] = 0;

            }
        }

        int carry=0, n,x=a_len-1,y=b_len-1;
        for(int i=0; i<ROW; ++i) {
            x=a_len-1;
            carry = 0;
            for(int j=(COL-1)-i; j>=0; --j) {
                if((x>=0)&&(y>=0))  {
                    n = (num(a[x])*num(b[y]))+carry;
                    mat[i][j] = n%10;
                    carry = getCarry(n);
                }
                else if((x>=-1)&&(y>=-1)) mat[i][j] = carry;
                x=x-1;
            }
            y=y-1;
        }

        carry = 0;
        int sum_arr[COL];
        for(int i =0; i<COL; ++i) sum_arr[i] = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<ROW; ++i) {
            for(int j=COL-1; j>=0; --j) {
                sum_arr[j] += (mat[i][j]);
            }
        }
        int temp;
        for(int i=COL-1; i>=0; --i) {
            sum_arr[i] += carry;
            temp = sum_arr[i];
            sum_arr[i] = sum_arr[i]%10;
            carry = getCarry(temp);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<COL; ++i) {
            ret.push_back(char(sum_arr[i]+48));
        }

        while(ret[0]=='0'){
            ret = ret.substr(1,ret.length()-1);
        }
        return ret;
}

void printhuge(string a) {
    cout<<"\n";
    for(string::iterator i = a.begin(); i!=a.end(); ++i) {
        cout<<*i;
    }
}

int main() {
    string a,b;
    cin>>a>>b;
    printhuge(mult(a,b));
    return 0;
}
```

All is working fine, but I need to use char[] instead of "string" . I know it's silly but I have to use that format necessary. So - how can I convert the code to work with char[] definition ?

Any ideas is greatly appreciated, Thanks :)

Comment: Do you need to *produce* `char*` as the end result, or do you need to drop the use of strings altogether?

Comment: Do you need to use `char*` as part of the assignment requirements? I can see no other reason to avoid using C++ strings.

Comment: The end result must be a char...

Comment: What about the intermediate results? Can they remain `std::string`? Also `char[]` is fixed size (C++ support for variable-size arrays is a compiler extension). Do you mean `char*` instead of `char[]`?

Comment: No, all must be in char[]...Any ideas

Comment: @DiscreteMath'sFan, if that is the case... You have your work cut out for you...

Comment: So you want us to rewrite your code using C-style strings? Give it a shot by yourself before you ask the question.

Answer (score 4):

Provided you don't need to modify the C string (the char array), i. e. it can be `const char[]` or `const char *`, use the `c_str()` method of `std::string`:

```
const char *c_string = str.c_str();
```

**Edit:** so your problem is that you should not use `std::string` at all. Well, in this case, this is how you can replace C++ strings with C strings:

- C strings are 0-terminated arrays of `char` (or `const char`). As usually, in certain conditions, they decay into pointers.
- You can get the length of a C string using the `strlen()` function in `<string.h>`.
- To append strings to each other, use the `strcat()` or `strncat()` functions. ***Beware of buffer sizes and the extra space for the terminating NUL character!***
- etc.

Comment: This is a fine answer is the OP is OK using the strings until the final stage, but it sounds like he may want to drop the use of strings altogether.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes, of course, but then that's a different question. **Now** he asked "how to obtain C string from `std::string`", and not "how to avoid strings when multiplying large numbers".

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding... I need to REPLACE string with char[]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more

Answer (score 2):

Call [`std::string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) on your string objects.

Just make sure the buffer isn't modifed by the functions.

**Edit**

Or, if you need to accept a `char[]`, just create a `string` out of it.

Comment: @DiscreteMath'sFan, you aren't allowed to use string at all? Or are the functions merely supopsed to take a `char*` argument?